# Should I use == or [NSManagedObject isEqual:] to compare managed objects in the same context?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Let's say variable A and B hold instances of managed objects in the same managed object context. I need to make sure that they are associated with the same "record" in the persistent store. The section on [Faulting and Uniquing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) in the Core Data Programming Guide says that:

> Core Data ensures that—in a given managed object context—an entry in a persistent store is associated with only one managed object.

From this, it seems that a pointer comparison is sufficient for my purpose. Or does it ever make sense to use isEqual: to compare managed objects in the same context?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `==` to determine if two pointers point to the same object. Use `-isEqual` to determine if two objects are "equal", where the notion of equality depends on the objects being compared. `-isEqual:` normally compares the values returned by the `-hash` method. I wrote previously that it seemed possible that `-isEqual:` might return true if two managed objects contain the same values. That's clearly not right. There are some caveats in the docs about making sure that the hash value for a mutable object doesn't change while it's in a collection, and that knowing whether a given object is in a collection can be difficult. It seems certain that the hash for a managed object doesn't depend on the data that that object contains, and much more likely that it's connected to something immutable about the object; the object's `-objectID` value seems a likely candidate.

Given all that, I'm changing my opinion ;-). Each record is only represented once in a given context, so `==` is probably safe, but `-isEqual:` seems to better express your intention.

Comment: What exactly does `-isEqual` compare for managed objects? I can't seem to find anything in Apple's docs.

Comment: `isEqual` for managed objects operates the same an ==, i.e. it determines if the two variable names point to the same actual object in memory. It does not attempt to compare attribute values. Although, `isEqual` is inherited from NSObject, the comparisons are overridden and custom to each particular class hierarchy. NSArray and NSString have different test for equality. Since managed objects are unique in their object graph, not two managed objects are ever "equal" in any meaningful sense. Even if they contain identical values, they are still in different locations in the object graph.

Comment: Thanks @TechZen for the detailed explanation. While what you are saying seems right, do you have a source from where I can verify this? i.e. `isEqual` doing a pointer comparison for managed objects.

Comment: Not sure where or if it is documented. I tested it with two managed objects with the same attributes values versus two variables assigned to the same object. Only the the latter produced `isEqual` as true. That should be expected owing to the uniqueness of managed objecjs.

Comment: Ok. @Caleb's answer seems to imply otherwise though i.e. `isEqual:` compares attribute values.

Comment: Edited answer above. I think TechZen and I are probably both wrong: -isEqual: should look at the objectID, not the pointer or the contents.

Comment: +1 for pointing to `objectID`. That _could_ be what `isEqual:` is doing -- I never thought of that. I am still not marking it as accepted though -- I am hoping that we can get a concrete answer on what `isEqual:` does exactly for managed objects.

Comment: This had been idle for a while -- I believe the answer and the discussion above has _probably_ led us to the right conclusion. So I have accepted this answer.

Comment: Generally agree with `-isEqual:` - another point to note is that users of NSManagedObject are explicitly told in strong terms not to override  `isEqual:`, per: 'Methods you Must Not Override:

NSManagedObject itself customizes many features of NSObject so that managed objects can be properly integrated into the Core Data infrastructure. Core Data relies on NSManagedObject’s implementation of the following methods, which you therefore absolutely must not override:... isEqual:, hash, superclass, class, self, zone...

Answer (score 22):

Pointer comparison is fine for objects retrieved from a single managed object context, the documentation on uniquing you quote promises as much.

`ObjectID` should be used for testing object equality across managed object contexts.

`isEqual` does not do attribute tests, because it is documented to not fault the object. In fact, looking at the disassembled function it is definitely just a pointer compare.

So the semantics of the equality test for managed objects are simply "points to the same object (record) in the managed object context" and will compare false for objects in different contexts.

Answer (score 10):

Warning: Since NSManagedObject isEqual compares objectIDs, a comparison can fail if one instance is using the temporary objectID and the other instance is using the permanent objectID.

Background: When an NSManagedObject is created, it is assigned a temporary objectID. It is converted into a permanent objectID when the NSManagedObject is actually persisted into the store. You can see the difference if you print the objectID:

x-coredata:///MyEntity/t03BF9735-A005-4ED9-96BA-462BD65FA25F118 (temporary ID)

x-coredata://EB8922D9-DC06-4256-A21B-DFFD47D7E6DA/MyEntity/p3 (permanent ID)

When an objectID is converted to permanent, instances of the NSManagedObject in other threads and collections are not updated. So if you put an NSManagedObject into an NSArray when it has a temporary objectID, using methods like containsObject will fail if you try to find the object with the permanent objectID. Remember containsObject uses isEqual.

Finally, a couple of useful methods are NSManagedObjectID isTemporaryID and NSManagedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:.

Comment: Does that mean I should reload all collections that hold core data entities every time I save?

Comment: This is a useful answer, and still valid in 2021.