# isEqual of NSManagedObject - How does it determine equality?

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, key

I'm dealing with an NSMutableDictionary with NSManagedObject keys. Some of the data in my keys are going to be mutated, but the NSMutableDictionary class reference states that the keys are copied when using setObject! And when I want to access values using keys, it's going to compare the key I give it to the keys in the key list.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I can't find on the NSManagedObject class reference what isEqual does. Does it compare every value, compare some unique identifiers, compare the memory addresses, or something else?

I've seen some unsure answers here: [Should I use == or [NSManagedObject isEqual:] to compare managed objects in the same context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298005/should-i-use-or-nsmanagedobject-isequal-to-compare-managed-objects-in-the), one of them saying that it compares the hash methods. Hash codes are not necessarily unique identifiers of objects, right?

Comment: How are you getting this to work? NSManagedObjects to not conform to NSCoding, and therefore should not work as keys of an NSDictionary. 
Instead, I would suggest using [nsManagedObject objectID] as the key, as it conforms to NSCopy, and you can use isEqual: as you would expect.

Comment: It said in the NSManagedObject class reference that it works with most data structures. I might be missing something because I'm fairly new to this, but Xcode seems to let me put them in as keys. Anyway, the objectID thing sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Well, to clarify, that IS a good idea. I'm using objectIDs as keys. I don't know why I didn't think of that before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see others have answered in the comments - but for the "officiality" of it - here is the proper detailed answer.

Since `NSManagedObjcet` class does not conform to `<NSCoding>` protocol - it cannot serve as a key in `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`.

Rather - you would want to use the `objectID` property of your managedObject as key in a dictionary. `objectID` is an NSString, which of course conforms to `NSCoding`.

Using `objectID` has another benefit. If you have more than one `NSManagedObjectContext`, The same entity will have a different instance of the `NSManagedOBject` for each  `NSManagedObjectContext`. The only way to know they are one - is via their `objectID` property - which will be `isEqual`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't remember why I was asking this question or if I somehow managed to have a dictionary with `NSManagedObject` keys, but this is the right answer.

Comment: I still miss some understanding there - regarding the title of your original question - I do not yet fully know what isEqual is doing for NSManagedObjects - but the scenario you described in your question implied this answer will help. If you find it useful --- could you up vote it?