# XCTAssertEqualObjects and NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, xctest

I'm not sure why `XCTAssertEqualObjects` is saying that these objects aren't equal:

```
[PlayerService_Test testMapping] : ((player) equal to (mappingTest.destinationObject)) failed: ("<PlayerVO: 0x8ec13e0> (entity: PlayerVO; id: 0x8ec1440 <x-coredata:///PlayerVO/t4741C1FA-8A84-4A41-9F2E-9476B1900CFD2> ; data: {
    activities =     (
    );
    dob = "1986-08-15 23:00:00 +0000";
    firstName = Ahmed;
    fullName = nil;
    lastName = Ahmed;
    middleName = Ahmed;
    sex = m;
})") is not equal to ("<PlayerVO: 0x8f09660> (entity: PlayerVO; id: 0x8f57490 <x-coredata:///PlayerVO/t4741C1FA-8A84-4A41-9F2E-9476B1900CFD3> ; data: {
    activities =     (
    );
    dob = "1986-08-15 23:00:00 +0000";
    firstName = Ahmed;
    fullName = nil;
    lastName = Ahmed;
    middleName = Ahmed;
    sex = m;
})")
```

Could it be because of the `activities` field? Is there another way to loosely compare two objects without iterating and comparing its properties?

Comment: So this has helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298005/should-i-use-or-nsmanagedobject-isequal-to-compare-managed-objects-in-the

Answer (score 1):

So this works, but it's pretty nasty:

```
XCTAssertEqualObjects([player valueForKey:@"firstName"], [mappingTest.destinationObject valueForKey:@"firstName"]);
XCTAssertEqualObjects([player valueForKey:@"middleName"], [mappingTest.destinationObject valueForKey:@"middleName"]);
XCTAssertEqualObjects([player valueForKey:@"lastName"], [mappingTest.destinationObject valueForKey:@"lastName"]);
XCTAssertEqualObjects([player valueForKey:@"dob"], [mappingTest.destinationObject valueForKey:@"dob"]);
XCTAssertEqualObjects([player valueForKey:@"sex"], [mappingTest.destinationObject valueForKey:@"sex"]);
```